# python : Choose class from __init__ parameters

Tags: python, inheritance, instantiation

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def area(self):
        return self.a*self.b

class Square(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self,a):
        super().__init__(a,a)
```

What would be the most pythonic way of designing the two classes such that :

```
Rectangle(2,2)
```

returns a propper `Square` object ?

Comment: Even if you could make it happen, it's unlikely to be a good idea to have a class instantiation return something other than the class you instantiated. Instead you perhaps you could use the Factory pattern?

Comment: For exemple a ShapeFactory class, with a method CreateShape that will choose between the two classes and return either a Rectangle object or a Square object ?

Comment: Yes, although in Python the factory itself doesn't need to be a class, you could have `create_shape()` as a standalone function.

Comment: Seems better. Ok i'll try that thanks for the tip